# HP Vertica - How do I specify date formats for the CSV parsers

Tags: csv, parsing, timestamp, date-formatting, vertica

In Vertica 7.2, I'm using COPY with fdelimitedparser. I would like to be able to specify a date or datetime format for some but not all of the columns. Different date columns can have different formats.

I can't list all columns like when using COPY without a parser, since I have many files with different column combinations, and I would rather avoid writing a script to generate my copy command for each file.

Is there any way to do this ?

Additionally, how do I know which parser natively accepts which date format ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vertica filler option when loading data.

**See example here :**

[Transform data during load in Vertica](http://www.aodba.com/transform-data-during-load-in-vertica-use-variable-with-copy/)

**A small example also :**

```
dbadmin=> \! cat /tmp/file.csv
2016-19-11

dbadmin=> copy tbl1 (v_col_1 FILLER date FORMAT 'YYYY-DD-MM',col1 as v_col_1) from '/tmp/file.csv';
 Rows Loaded
-------------
           1
(1 row)

dbadmin=> select * from tbl1;
    col1
------------
 2016-11-19
(1 row)

dbadmin=> copy tbl1 (v_col_1 FILLER date FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD',col1 as v_col_1) from '/tmp/file.csv';
 Rows Loaded
-------------
           1
(1 row)

dbadmin=> select * from tbl1;
    col1
------------
 2016-11-19
 2017-07-14
(2 rows)
```

hope this helped

Comment: You don't need filler for this. You can specify format directly on a column.  Also notice he is using a flex parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format keyword as part of the COPY command

see below eg from Vertica Forum :

```
create table test3 (id int, Name varchar(16), dt date, f2  int);
CREATE TABLE

vsql=> \!cat /tmp/mydata.data
1|foo|29-Jan-2013|100.0
2|bar|30-Jan-2013|200.0
3|egg|31-Jan-2013|300.0
4|tux|01-Feb-2013|59.9

vsql=> copy test3
vsql-> ( id, Name, dt format 'DD#MON#YYYY', f 2)
vsql-> from '/tmp/mydata.data'  direct  delimiter '|' abort on error;
 Rows Loaded 
-------------
           4
(1 row)

vsql=> select * from test3;
 id | Name |     dt     |  f2  
----+------+------------+----------
  1 | foo  | 2013-01-29 | 100.0000
  2 | bar  | 2013-01-30 | 200.0000
  3 | egg  | 2013-01-31 | 300.0000
  4 | tux  | 2013-02-01 |  59.9000
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this requires me to enter the right set of column names in the parenthesis, and what I tried to explain is that I use a flex parser because the column combinations tend to vary a lot between my different files.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand , you need to chooses between “Simple to load “ And “Fast
>   to consume”,   flex table will add some impacts on the  consumers ,
>   some info on that : Flex table is row  based storage  it will consume
>   more disk space and its have  zero capability to encode the data , 
>   you  have the  ability to materialized the relevant columns as
>   columnar ,  but the data will  be persist twice , on both ROW and
>   columnar storages  (load time should be slower, and it will require) 
>   .  At a Query time , if you plan to query only the materialized
>   columns you should be ok , but if not , you should expect to have
>   performance issues

Comment: Actually my table is not Flex. I declared the table considering the exhaustiveness of possible columns. But my data sources each implement some of the columns only. I'm calling the parser flex because I want it to read headers and not explicitly define column name and order at load, but all columns and data types were already declared at table creation.